how to find points satisfying the FONC
minimize $f(x) = xy$ subject to $x + y \ge 2$, $x \le y$.
I want to find all points satisfying the FONC.
My friend says $(1,1)$ is the only points but I am kinda confused.
I understand there is no interior point.
On the boundary, why can't $(0,2)$ or $(0.5,1.5)$ be a point satisfying the FONC?

FONC? Is this a commonly used acronym?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@RedFive I'm guessing FONC is "first order necessary conditions." To that end, don't use acronyms that may not be commonly used.

sorry, I meant first order necessary condition.

It seems that FONC means first order necessary conditions as mentioned in the comment and another similar question posted a while back. But it doesn't really help you solve the problem. I can determine whether the expression in question has a minimum or not without using the FONC. The verdict is that the minimum doesn't exist. To see this true, put $a = x+y, b = y - x$, then $xy = \dfrac{(x+y)^2 - (y-x)^2}{4}= \dfrac{a^2-b^2}{4}$. Thus we are minimizing the function $f(a,b) = \dfrac{a^2-b^2}{4}$ such that $a \ge 2, b \ge 0$. This function has no minimum value as we can let $a = 2, b \to \infty$ and $f(a,b) \to -\infty$.
